# Python - unable to convert 1.72e-05 to a float value

Tags: python

I have some values in scientific notation in a csv file and am trying to convert them in to float/decimal values using a Python 3 script (inherited from some one). For that I am using float(string) but it is failing to convert some of the values.

Here is an example:

```
U:\>py
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> float('1.72e-05')
1.72e-05
>>>
```

Somehow it is not working for some values such as the above.

Those scientific notation values are coming from a different system and I have no clue how they are created.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the expected output for the example above?

Comment: What you receive as result *is* a float, just displayed in scientific notation.

Comment: I would like it to return a real float, not in scientific notation value. I am trying to replace scientific notation values in the file with actual float values as a string so that it can be loaded in to SQL Server.

Comment: Then what you want *isn't* a "real float", it's a string representation of a float.

Comment: It's working fine.  You're passing a string `'1.72e-05'` to `float`, and it's returning the float value `1.72e-05`.  That's not a string, it's a float.  If it were a string, it would be surrounded by single quotes.  You can confirm it by doing `type(float('1.72e-05'))`.  If you want to re-format it into a string, using a different format, then you can use the `format` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert it to a string, then do so.

```
value = float('1.72e-05')
string_value = "%f" % value
```

Comment: Should be `"%.7f" % value` in this case.

Comment: Thank you all for your amazing answers. I just need two digits after the decimal and this is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Use the build-in function [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to display  scientific notation as decimals.

```
>>> format(float('1.72e-05'), 'f')
'0.000017'

>>> format(float('1.72e-05'), '.7f')
'0.0000172'
```